# React Native Variable assignment when doing conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that builds a View, but only some of the items should render depending on the data. However, for each item that is rendered, I keep track of its count. Is there a way to do this inside the render()?

ie, something like:

```
render() {
    let count = 0;
    return (
        <View>

            { if condition1:
                 this.renderOptions(name='one', current_count=count);
                 count += 1;
            }
            { if condition2:
                 this.renderOptions(name='two', current_count=count);
                 count += 1;
            }
            { if condition3:
                 this.renderOptions(name='three', current_count=count);
            }

        </View>
    );
}
```

Basically, `count` should keep track of how many elements were actually rendered given the specific condition. It increments each time a condition is true and the `renderOptions()` renders specific items based on `count`.

I know there is the `&&` operator, but something like this throws an error:

```
{ condition1 && this.renderOptions(name='one', current_count=count) }
{ condition1 && count++ }
```

But this errors:

> undefined is not an object

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
{ condition1 && count++ }
```

You can write

```
{ condition1 && incrementCounter }
```

And do count++ in the `incrementCounter` function (that will return null)

Comment: But `count` is a local variable declared inside the `render()`?

Comment: maintain that in state instead!